# How to retrieve records with conditions and "String" numbers with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to write an HQL query in my java web application bean. In the database table, there is a column which includes numeric datas but not as a number, as a string (varchar2). It is a part of my project design. User will enter a numeric value on GUI and with an HQL query, bean will retrieve datas. An example :

35 (database value) <= 40 (user entered value)

these values are string. Not number. How can i build my HQL Query String?
I dont think that, using "LIKE" clause will be solution, or do?
I hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that my solution crashes when your column (casted to numeric) exceeds numeric(19,2)*

```
where (case when isNumeric(YOUR_COLUMN) = 1 then cast(YOUR_COLUMN as big_integer) else 99999 end) < USER_INPUT_VALUE
```

Maybe you need to adjust the else branch - I chose *99999* as default value when YOUR_COLUMN is not numeric so it would never be considered as a valid value